# Possible to separate integration test and unit test reports in Sonar?

Tags: selenium, junit, sonarqube

I know it is possible to separate Integration and Unit test code coverage in Sonar, but is it possible to retrieve separate pass/fail results for Integration and Unit tests? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this is currently not possible.

Feel free to start a discussion on this topic on Sonar user mailing-list.